# Scheme code that will return zero if an atom is not in a list

Tags: scheme, racket

I have a program that takes an atom and a list as parameters. The program is supposed to output the position of the atom in the current list. My code works for all the conditions except when the given atom is not in the list. I want my program to output '0' if the atom is not in the list.

```
    [if (not(eq? atm (cdr lst)) 0)]
```

I am trying to say 'if the position of atm is not in the cdr of lst then return 0.

This does not work, how do I go about doing this?

Comment: The cdr of a list is another list. List elements are in the cars.

Comment: Show the whole function.

Comment: It's the `car` of all the `cons` that holds the values you should be comparing. The `cdr` is just the list without the first element pair. Also if you want Scheem to output you need to use `display` since an expression only prints the result when in a REPL as a part of the REPL functionality and not your code.

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I suspect that what you _really_ need is to know how to return if an element is not in a list _after_ reaching the end of the list.